# Anonymous authentication in mvc 5 project not working on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to authenticate Anonymously in my mvc 5 project, it seems to work fine in my local host, but after deploying to production server, it does not see see the anonymous authentication tag in web.config file, i am having this error: Object reference not set to instance of an object, meaning the Request.Anonymous field is null, i dont know how to get this work in mvc 5 e-commerce site on production, i will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Here is my code:
I added this line of code to the config file inside system.web

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS" cookieTimeout="4320" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" />
```

And this is how i reference it in my code behind:

```
var getRecord = (from u in db.ShoppingCarts.Where(x => x.CartSessionID.Equals(Request.AnonymousID)) select u).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your authentication setting in IIS [image: IIS Image attached]

Enable **Anonymous Authentication** which will automatically change your **web.config**

Hopefully this will help you ..

Comment: I dont have access to IIS, i am using a shared hosting account, or is there any better approach to this?

Comment: Then have you tried this

' <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web> '

This allows all users...